# File not found error while Installing Numpy on Windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, installation

I have just  started programming in Python to learn and explore about Data analysis. To accomplish this I tried downloading numpy and pandas from cmd prompt, I already have python 2.7 installed.But each time it gives me file not found error for numpy and panda.

It seems I don't have the points to post an image. 
that's  sad but please let me know if you need any info

Update: Python is 32-bit , I checked this by running the platform query.

I am using easy_install.exe to install numpy and panda so don't the versions

I go to the directory where my scripts are there in the cmd prompt and type "easy_insatll.exe numpy"

Am I doing it wrong ?

Can I use Anaconda to install these packages after I have python already installed?

Please let me know if you need any info.

Comment: Could you give the exact error message? Even just a text copy of it.

Comment: Try a full scientific python distribution such as [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads). Unfortunately installing python modules on Windows is not as straightforward as it is on *nix.

Comment: What error do you get?  Are both python and numpy 64-bit or 32-bit. What do you mean by downloading from cmd. Are you trying pip install?

Comment: If you're just starting with Python you should definitely use one of the existing scientific Python distributions.  Otherwise you will find installation to be an almost insurmountable hurdle.